# Explorerer and Discoverer

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-in-context

I'm trying to figure out whether exploration can imply discovery and discovery imply exploration. I think these two terms are linked.

- An explorer can discover when he explores.
- A discoverer may need to explorer in order to discover.

Imaging a person who is sent into a cave to explore it and he discovers ancient glyphs and objects. Or imaging a person who is working on discovering a new energy source. He explores different sources and places.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You don't have to be an explorer to discover something—"I just discovered I don't like broccoli, though I never set out on that quest"—and you're not a discoverer until you, er, discover something. What's hard to understand about that?

Comment: Another significant difference is that it's perfectly natural even now to say things like *Dr Livingstone was an explorer* (not such a common "occupation" today, since most places have already been explored). But you wouldn't be likely to identify someone by saying, for example, *Mr Smith was a discoverer* - and so far as I know that usage was *never* "natural".

Comment: This more of a logic question than a language one. As a true example, getting on a bicycle implies I am going to ride it. And by riding a bicycle, it is understood I got on it. Your examples could apply but in other cases, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly an **explorer** is someone who sets out with the *intention* to discover something.  The explorer might fail to discover anything, in which case we could  say:

> He **discovered** nothing but destitution, dejection, and death

but while this sounds nice it's not the same as making a *significant* discovery.

A **discoverer** is someone who has discovered something, ordinarily through *some kind* of exploration, but possibly by accident.  For example, there used to be [this commercial for Reese's Peanut Butter cups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJLDF6qZUX0), in which two people accidentally **discover** that chocolate and peanut butter taste good together.

(Actually Reese was a real person who spent many years **exploring** different confections before he **discovered** this particular, very successful, combination.)

So the terms are *related* but not *synonymous*.  An explorer might be a discoverer, and a discoverer an explorer, but neither requires the other.